# Auto load Swagger UI params in a link?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have a Swagger UI page documenting a REST api. I can already send a link to a specific call by using a url like this: http://my-api/apidocs/#!/MyResource/someEndpoint

Does anybody know if I can specify a value for a parameter, so that when someone opens this link, it will be already preloaded with said value.

thanks

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I haven't, question is still open